# Fazer select de hoje até uma semana atras

Tags: php, mysql

quero fazer um select em sql da data de hoje até uma semana atras, achei esse código aqui

```
'SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE registro BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY registro ASC';
```

mais ele funciona apenas se o campo do banco de dados for de date, o meu está como datetime, como eu poderia adaptar esse código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim usando DATE_ADD() ou DATE_SUB():

```
    SELECT * FROM tabela
    WHERE coluna_date_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

ou

```
    SELECT * FROM tabela
    WHERE coluna_date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Sem estas funções pode fazer assim:

```
    SELECT * FROM tabela
    WHERE coluna_date_time >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

ou

```
    SELECT * FROM tabela
    WHERE coluna_date_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: obrigado deu certinho.